# Should I use raid 0 with my optibay drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, optical-drive, raid

I installed a 120gb SSD today. My optibay currently holds my MBP stock drive (5400 RPM HD 320GB). Since they have different memory sizes, should I put them in raid 0? The only reason why I want raid 0 for convenience. I want to store all my music and photos in the optibay drive, but it seems like there would be a ton of configuration nuances with iTunes and iPhoto. If one drive were to fail, however, then I would lose all my data. Could someone please correct me on this? Any help and instructions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the saying goes: "The difference between RAID 1 and RAID 0 is that the zero stands for how many files you're going to have after a hard disk failure."

Putting your 320 GB hard drive and your 120 GB SSD will allow you to share the space in between the two drives, but the risk in doing so is that you may have a failure at some point that makes your data unrecoverable.

If you want to set up your hard drives in a RAID 0, I would recommend also setting up a backup solution that regularly backs up your files to a location that is outside of your laptop. That makes sure that your data can be recovered in the event of a failure.